# Save the output of the corenlp in a file

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

Is there any approach to saving the output of core NLP sentiment analysis in a file rather than messaging in the output?

**my code that messages the result :**

`
   NLP.init();

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("Qxykv655aAS4L5JFXszO1Ym0o");
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("EUSziBboNBzn8arsxt2cOgPJWGhs8uCK7yWwZSpKdbzBohRost");
cb.setOAuthAccessToken("825807469238706181-CD69DQaULHhZzNzyIPxDQaTXc4KIDHK");
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("Y836DvgGset2FMfe9VX3wlzaT69HV0qE7oQumZQCuT7vR");

TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

    public void onStatus(Status status) {
        if (((NLP.findSentiment(status.getText()) == 1) | (NLP.findSentiment(status.getText()) == 0))
        ){
            System.out.println(status.getText());

            if (status.getGeoLocation() != null) {

                double latitude = status.getGeoLocation().getLatitude();
                double longitude = status.getGeoLocation().getLongitude();
                if (latitude != 20 && longitude != 78) {
                    return;
                }

            }
        }
    }

};


FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
String keywords[] = {"pizza, junk food, hamburger"};
fq.track(keywords);
fq.language(new String[]{"en"});
twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

`

[image]

Comment: Once the chat has been removed from this post, it looks rather bare. I don't know this technology, but is there any further detail you can add about what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: thank @halfer for yoyr comment . Its corenlp that shows the result as message, for example shows the sentiment of the tweets as negative, positive, but it shows that as message in the output rather than saving them in a file

Comment: Can we see an example of the console output, edited into the question? Assuming you're using a *nix-like OS, can you use `grep` to filter them?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Would it be worth indicating what you want filtered in/out, do you think?

Comment: I just want to have this output in a file, not more